# How to make column values more presentable

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table containing the following fields:

- version
- id
- set_value
- marker

I want to write a SELECT statement to query them. However, the values in the column `marker` are not easily readable. I would like to present a substring of that column. My question is how do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `LEFT()` or `SUBSTR()`?

Comment: Can you provide some context? You want to "present a substring of the column". What sort of substring? What is the value in the `marker` column? What is the value you want to display? What is the logic for getting the part you want to display from the value in the `marker` column? Do you want the first 5 characters, for example? Do  you want to find the first `(` and return everything up to the next `)`? Or do you want to do something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
SELECT version,
       id,
       set_value,
       SUBSTR(marker, 1, 10) AS marker
  FROM ...
```

to select just the first ten characters of `marker`, and still have the resulting column be named "marker".

(See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions169.htm.)

Comment: Ok great that's what I needed, now the value I am looking for in the column can be variable for example: 1#1#com.jn    IN this example I want to extract the "com" however the "com" can be located at different "depths" in the string. How can I extract it. Thanks!!

Comment: @welfinator: You need to clearly define the mapping. In the case of `1#1#com.jn`, you say you want the `com`. How did you determine that? How do you know you want `com`, and not `1` or `jn` or `#`? In order to write this query, you'll need a very general rule that can map *any* value of `marker` to the desired output.

Comment: You can use the INSTR function or the REGEXP_INSTR family of functions for regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [substr](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php) function.